# What does "create" mean in java

Tags: java

I tried to find it here and over the Web itself but I could not.

I have something like this in code:

```
private static myClassName create(listOfArguments) {}
```

It looks for me like it would be myClassName constructor but normal constructor looks a little bit different. What exactly this **create** mean, and what's it for?

Comment: It means whatever you want it to mean, though for clarity it may be best if it creates something

Comment: it depends what's inside the brackets you took care of clipping off :-)

Comment: It's the name of the method that you're showing us.  Its meaning is: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/create

Comment: You could as well call it `potato`. Behaviour doesn't come from naming methods. It's the other way around.

Comment: @QBrute there .

Comment: Simple.  That is a method that returns an instance of `myClassName`.  The `create` is the method name, and the implication is that the method "creates" an instance.  (Obviously, it won't compile.  A method with a non-void return type needs a `return` statement to return the method's result.)

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing else but a private "factory" method that probably calls a constructor internally.

Like [Optional.of()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-) but just that: *private*.

Meaning; normally you would write code as:

```
MyClass whatever = new MyClass(args ...
```

using that method, you can write

```
MyClass whatever = create(args ...
```

That is all there is to this.

The *one* good reason I see to have such a method: to avoid code duplication. When you have 10 new statements in your code, then a changing that means touching 10 lines. When you have that create method, some changes could be contained inside that method. Nonetheless; having a *static* **private** factory method is a rather uncommon, surprising pattern.

Answer (score 1):

`create` here is a method name.

There is a pattern called `Factory method` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern which looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyClass(String arg) {
        // ... init
    }

    public static create(String arg) {
        return new MyClass(arg);
    }
}
```

It may be useful if you must have (or want to have) one 'fits all the cases constructor' (for example, to centralize your construction code). It may not be very convenient to use such a universal constructor, so you could create some factory methods:

```
public class StringOrDate {
    private final String string;
    private final Date date;

    private StringOrDate(String string, Date date) {
        this.string = string;
        this.date = date;
    }

    pubilc static createString(String string) {
        return new StringOrDate(string, null);
    }

    pubilc static createDate(Date date) {
        return new StringOrDate(null, date);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a method where `create` is a name, `myClassName` is a return type and `private` `static` - the access modifiers

Answer (score 0):

As other people have indicated, `create` *doesn't* have any special meaning in Java - this is just an ordinary method. In this case, the method does nothing and won't even compile because it doesn't return the type that it's required to return, but it's still just an ordinary method.